# ABPersonRemoveImageData working locally but not updating iCloud

Tags: ios, contacts, addressbook, abperson

I have application managing the iPhone/iPad contacts, one of the functionalities is to delete a specific tag for multiple contacts.

All the tags work perfectly fine, after removing the tag data, it get reflected on the iCloud and other devices for the same iCloud/Apple ID.

However, the Image of the contact doesn't get updated on the other devices.

I'm using ABPersonRemoveImageData to remove the image data for the contact.

Here the code sample:

```
if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) 
{
    ABPersonRemoveImageData(person, &error);
    ABAddressBookSave(ab, NULL);

    if (error != NULL) return false;
}
```

What is more weird, that for the same contact, and in the same code, I remove the birthday date and the image data, the removal of the birthday date gets reflected on other devices, while the Image still exists!

Is it a bug on the iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this too. If I update more than just the Image, it does sync the removed image.
My Guess, is YES, its another bug with iCloud.